# Accessing exchange rates converted into CAD from USD isn't working

Tags: php, json, api, curl, currency

I'm not sure why the test program below isn't getting the response from the API. Here is the [document](https://apilayer.com/marketplace/exchangerates_data-api?preview=true#pricing) for the API. It's working absolutely fine on the provider's playground. Running the test program below doesn't do anything at all.

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.apilayer.com/exchangerates_data/convert?to=CAD&from=USD&amount=1",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Content-Type: text/plain",
    "apikey: av5CJRrOA2Rclj4fai3UZF5NT7F9HmPr"
  ),
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET"
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
?>
```

Comment: Could you please link to the specific section of that documentation describing the request you are trying to make there - instead of just to the start page?

Comment: Updated the post with the link to the right page on the document.

Comment: it works from postman

Comment: How do I try postman? Please guide me on that. I do finally want this program to be a cron job.

Comment: Running the program on the localhost isn't working, but why

Comment: Why are you sending `Content-Type: text/plain`?